# How to return dictionary for longest list of dicts containing an item belonging to multiple list of dicts?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Really hard to phrase this question and I'm also having problems wrapping my head around how to figure this out.
Say I have the following dictionary.

```
mydict = { u'10441':
             [{u'quantity':   1, u'productId': 10441},
              {u'quantity':  25, u'productId': 10451},
              {u'quantity': 100, u'productId': 10461}],
           u'10451':
             [{u'quantity':   1, u'productId': 10451},
              {u'quantity':   4, u'productId': 10461}]
          }
```

How can I return the largest top-level sub-dictionary dictionary that has **productId** values in common with other dictionaries? For example, **productId** 10461 exists in both dictionaries (10441 and 10451) in mydict. I'd like to programmatically get the following since the value of this dict (10441) contains three items (dicts).

```
mydict1 = { u'10441':
             [{u'quantity':   1, u'productId': 10441},
              {u'quantity':  25, u'productId': 10451},
              {u'quantity': 100, u'productId': 10461}]
          }
```

Normally I'm able to figure this kind of stuff out but for some reason I'm having trouble with this one. Is there a way to figure this out idiomatically perhaps using filter or maybe a nested dict comprehension?

Comment: From what I understand you first need to calculate the number of common items for each dictionary and while doing it remember which one has the most common items ( you will need a max, some sort of index to remember which dict is the chosen one, and a maxNumberOfItems). When checking that dictA has more common items than max make sure you also check for equality. If they have the same number of common items update the index and maxNumberOfItems.

Comment: Are you looking for a specific product id (ie. will you be providing 10461)?  Or do you want to check for *all* product ids that are in *all* of the product dictionaries?

Comment: Not a specific id. There are numerous (over a thousand productIds) and I'd like to get the dictionary of the largest size by running the compare logic on each.

Answer (score 2):

With only two top-level dictionaries in your example, it's hard to see what you are really after. How many top-level dictionaries are we talking about? How many of them must share an Id? Let's see how you do this efficiently with pairwise comparisons, and hopefully you know where to go from there.

First, make an index (a set) of the Ids in each top-level dictionary.

```
myindex = dict()
for k, vals in mydict.items():
    myindex[k] = set(d["productId"] for d in vals)
```

Now we'll compare the indexes. To see if two dictionaries have IDs in common, take their intersection:

```
mydict1 = dict()
for key1, key2 in itertools.combinations(mydict, 2):
    if myindex[key1].intersection(myindex[key2]):
        bigkey = key1 if len(mydict[key1]) > len(mydict[key2]) else key2
        mydict1[bigkey] = mydict[bigkey]
```

Comment: Sorry alexis for not providing enough context. There will be an indeterministic amount of dictionaries all of which will have the same sort of structure above. I just gave two of these but there will be more with different productIds. I'll take your suggestion and try this out. Thank you for assistance.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that out, but what do you do about overlaps between multiple dictionaries? If an Id appears in dictionary A, B and C (which will give you three pairwise overlaps), what do you do? I only compare pairs, since that's the only scenario your question describes.

Comment: I had the same question actually and realized that once I tried your code out. There may be a possible 3 pairs scenario that I would need to run compares against but no more than that. I'm leaning towards the solution Brendan provided above in the try block which should take into account any number of dictionaries provided that I have the productId that I'm using as the filter.

Comment: Sure, if it works just do it. It's trivial to make a reverse index of everything that uses each product id, but I won't bother if you already have a usable solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this.  The `try/except` is just there in case *none* of the id lists contain the given product id (which will cause `max` to raise a `ValueError` because of the empty sequence).

The answer is somewhat ambiguous when multiple items in your product dictionary contain the same number of items (ie. there is more than one "longest" dictionary).

```
pid = 10461

try:
    mid, mlist = max(((id, dlist) for id, dlist in mydict.iteritems() if any(d['productId'] == pid for d in dlist)), key=lambda x: len(x[1]))
    mdict1 = {mid: mlist}
except ValueError:
    mdict1 = None
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `id2parents` to keep track of the parent ids of each product id. For any product id with same number of parents as the number of elements in `mydict`, it must exist in every directory. Collect such directory id into `parent_ids`, and sort by its size, and select the first one:

```
mydict = { u'10441':
        [{u'quantity':   1, u'productId': 10441},
            {u'quantity':  25, u'productId': 10451},
            {u'quantity': 100, u'productId': 10461}],
        u'10451':
        [{u'quantity':   1, u'productId': 10451},
            {u'quantity':   4, u'productId': 10461}]
        }

id2parents = {}
for parent_id, subdirs in mydict.iteritems():
    for d in subdirs:
        id2parents.setdefault(d['productId'], []).append(parent_id)

parent_ids = []
for product_id, dirs in id_dirs.iteritems():
    if len(dirs) == len(mydict.values()):
        parent_ids += dirs

parent_ids.sort(key=lambda parent_id: len(mydict[parent_id]), reverse=True)
mydict1 = mydict[parent_ids[0]]
print mydict1
```